Update billing address dropdown in checkout after AJAX call
I implemented the functionality of editing a customer address in checkout using AJAX. Everything works as expected for the shipping address, as it is updated automatically, but I can't figure out how to update the billing address dropdown without refreshing the page.
If I refresh the checkout page, the billing address dropdown is correctly populated. Also, I checked the quote, and the billing address is updated accordingly after updating the address, but from a UI perspective, I can't update the dropdown values in real time.
For updating the address I built a custom module and overwritten the saveNewAddress method, updating the address through a custom API endpoint and then selecting the address using selectShippingAddress(newAddress). After that, I updated the addressList() with the new details.
For the billing address, I tried to make changes in vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/billing-address/list.js, trying to update the addressOptions property but had no success. Also, I was looking for something that could reload the billing address but had no success as well.
How can I update the billing address dropdown in checkout without refreshing the page after successfully updating the shipping address?
Thank you!

I was able to update it. I only need to update the "inline" property of window.checkoutConfig.customerData.addresses to get the result and update the billing address dropdown.
The "inline" attribute is available on page load, but it's no longer available after I change the address.
